# Why doesn't my else work with ngIF in Agular 12?

Tags: typescript, angular12

I am brushing up my Angular knowledge and I came across an "else" to use if ngIf. In reality I think it is easier to use "valor !== false" to simulate an else. But if I need to give assistance in a code that uses I want to be prepared.

```
<div *ngIf="valor === 'teste'; else showOther">tttt</div>

<ng-temlate #showOther>
  <ng-content> outro </ng-content>
</ng-temlate>
```

I get this

```
Type 'HTMLElement' is not assignable to type 'TemplateRef<NgIfContext<boolean>>'.
```

[The code](https://angular-ivy-9wys8p.stackblitz.io)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote ng-temlate instead of ng-template.

But after fixing it, I still get this error:

> Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:  element cannot
> have content. ("   <div *ngIf="valor === 'teste' ; else
> showOther">Hello!   <ng-template #showOther>
> [ERROR ->]Content to render when condition is false.

Remove the ng-content tag, it will work. So the code should be:

```
<div *ngIf="valor === 'teste' ; else showOther">ttt</div>
<ng-template #showOther>
  Content to render when condition is false.
</ng-template>
```

Comment: It did worked!... it's all that matters!